# MySql, passing datareader, closing connections

Tags: mysql, vb.net, mysqldatareader

I know this is been asked in one for or another but I really can't find the best explanation.
I have a MySql DataReader function which is supposed to get one row from DB and return it "as is" because I want to process the data somewhere else

```
Private Function GetRow(ByVal sql As String) As MySqlDataReader

    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand

    Try

        cmd.Connection = New MySqlConnection() With {.ConnectionString = connString}
        cmd.CommandText = sql
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

        cmd.Connection.Open()

        Using dr As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)

            If dr.HasRows Then

                dr.Read()

            End If

            Return dr

        End Using

    Catch ex As MySqlException

        MsgBox(("Error #" & ex.Number & " while reading from DB has occurred: ") + vbCrLf + ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Error!")

    Finally

        cmd.Connection.Close()
        If cmd IsNot Nothing Then cmd.Dispose()

    End Try

    Return Nothing

End Function
```

Each time I used the function, connection remains opened (pooling disabled) so I started to use "using" statement for MySqlDataReader, along with "finally" dispose the connection itself. But now the function always returns DR with nothing, probably "using" dispose the Read() results.

Now the question is how can I pass the Read() entire row "as is"? Why should I still use Reader (if so complicated) if I can use a TableAdapter and pass the DataTable even for 1 row expected results?

Answer (score 0):

Please close, I found a elegant solution here, using dictionary as returns
[Storing results of a DataReader into an array in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11978127/storing-results-of-a-datareader-into-an-array-in-vb-net)

Excellent,