# vb net store multiple datareader results into one string variable

Tags: mysql, vb.net, executereader

i have a query like `SELECT ITEM FROM DETAIL WHERE TID="1"`.
that will return the results like

**m4, c1, f2, d5, k2**

i'm using `DATAREADER` to get the multiple value results

and here's the code

```
Dim res as string = "SELECT ITEM FROM DETAIL WHERE TID='1'"
CMD = New MySqlCommand(res, con)
result = CMD.ExecuteReader()
while result.HasRows
  result.Read()
  array(indeks) = result("ITEM")
end while
```

now instead storing results one by one into each array's index,

**array(0)=m4**

**array(1)=c1**,.....

i want to store all of that into single string variable **with format** like **'m4', 'c1', 'f2', 'd5', 'k2'**

the format is a single quote and commas(,) as separator for each results like example above (**the commas only appear if there's still a result**)

how could i do that in vb.net? i'm using mysql as database

UPDATED CODE

```
    Dim cnt As String = "select count(*) from detail where kode_faktur= '" & 1 & "' "
    Dim max As Int32
    CMD_sup = New MySqlCommand(cnt, conn.konek)
    max = Convert.ToInt32(CMD_sup.ExecuteScalar())
    CMD_sup.Connection.Close()

    Dim result As MySqlDataReader

    Dim resultString As String
    Dim isFirstResult = True

    Dim arayITEM() As String
    Dim res As String = "select kode_brg from detail where kode_faktur= '" & 1 & "' "
    CMD = New MySqlCommand(res, conn.konek)
    result = CMD.ExecuteReader()


    ReDim arayITEM(max)
    If result.HasRows Then
        For i As Integer = 0 To max - 1
            result.Read()
            arayITEM(i) = result("kode_brg")
        Next
    End If

    resultString = "'" & String.Join("','", arayITEM) & "'"
    'MsgBox("HASIL : " & resultString)
```

here's the screenshoot

[image]

i don't need separator at the end of last array's element (`,''`)

Comment: Have you tried string concatenation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this :

```
Dim res as string = "SELECT ITEM FROM DETAIL WHERE TID='1'"
CMD = New MySqlCommand(res, con)
result = CMD.ExecuteReader()
Dim resultString as String = ""
Dim isFirstResult = True
while result.HasRows
  result.Read()
  If Not isFirstResult Then 
    resultString &= string.Format(",'{0}'",result("ITEM"))
  Else 
    isFirstResult = False
    resultString &= string.Format("'{0}'",result("ITEM"))
  End If
end while
```

Or if you want to keep using the array but also need the single string version, you can convert the array using `String.Join` :

```
Dim resultString As String = "'" & String.Join("','", array) & "'"
```

`String.Join` is clever enough to add separator only if next element exists. So both approach above should produce the same result.

Comment: thx for the answer, bro. i only need the values to be stored into single string. when i tried to display it using msgbox `MsgBox("Result: " & resstring)`. the program hangs and the error popped up. And what is the `boolean` variable role here? could you please explain it to me?

Comment: `isFirstResult` is to avoid adding preceding comma (',') for the first result. It should only be added to 2nd-last result.

Comment: and what is the error message? I can't guess, it kinda work fine here. I tested by looping through list of string though, instead of looping through DataReader

Comment: here's the error `Value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of String)' cannot be converted to '1-dimensional array of String'`. and the code is on my post

Comment: more logical thing to try: change this `String.Join("','", aray)` to this `String.Join("','", aray.ToArray())`

Comment: I tested with .NET 4.5, maybe in older version of .NET String.Join only accept parameter of type Array not List or other IEnumerable collection

Comment: i've modified my code using array now not `LIST`. but it still getting error.. logically, `STRING JOIN` should be correct for joining the array. i've updated my code again on the post. could you please take a look at them again?

Comment: I checked your updated post. Still the same error message? If yes, I don't have any idea it should work fine, or try to stick with `List` but call `aray.ToArray()` as I mentioned above. Otherwise may I know what the error message now?

Comment: this is the error `"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."`

Comment: just try with `List` as I mentioned above bro, I'm sure that will work. The latest error because your array has not been initialized yet

Comment: i've fixed this.. it turned out that i forget to `redim` the array. that's why the `datareader` can't fill the array with values. **thx for the help like always, bro (y)**

Comment: Doesn't matter. Just my opinion, but dealing with `List` is more convenient than `Array` I mostly avoid using `Array` :p

Comment: how to make the separator stops when there's no more array element. i've updated my code and ss on my first post. sorry for the trouble again..

Comment: that means you have empty string in the last array element. in `while` loop you can add checking like : `If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(result("kode_brg")) Then arayITEM(i) = result("kode_brg")` to prevent adding empty string to the array

Comment: @har07.. thx u bro, you're right.. i recheck my `ReDim statement` and it turned out that i have set the array's capacity more than it should be, which resulting in 'extra empty element'..:)

Comment: I see, that's another reason to consider replacing array with list :D

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim res as string = "SELECT ITEM FROM DETAIL WHERE TID='1'"
CMD = New MySqlCommand(res, con)


' Read data from database
Dim result As New ArrayList()
Dr = CMD.ExecuteReader()

' Add each entry to array list
While Dr.Read()
    ' Insert each column into a dictionary
    Dim dict As New Dictionary(Of String, Object)
    For count As Integer = 0 To (Dr.FieldCount - 1)
        dict.Add(Dr.GetName(count), Dr(count))
    Next

    ' Add the dictionary to the ArrayList
    result.Add(dict & ", ")
End While
Dr.Close()
```

So, now you could loop through result with a for loop like this:

```
For Each dat As Dictionary(Of String, Object) In result
     Console.Write(dat("ColName"))
Next
```

Quite similar to how you would do it if it were just the DataReader:

```
While Dr.Read()
    Console.Write(Dr("ColName"))
End While
```

Code from : [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11978127/storing-results-of-a-datareader-into-an-array-in-vb-net)
I have modified it as what you want, but without testing.
hope can help you.